# How can the SOQL query limit be increased for our integration processes?

Tags: soql, integration, mulesoft

We are using Mule to integrate data to Salesforce and then return the Salesforce Id.  If we insert 1500 new records they are created in Salesforce successfully. However, when we try to retrieve the new SF Ids, something is limiting the records returned to 1000 and then the remaining 500 records error.  I found this documented in the SF Developer Limit Quick Reference...

A subquery that involves external objects can fetch up to 1,000 rows of data.

Could this be what is causing this issue?  What is considered an external object?  Is there a way to increase this limit or do you have any suggestion on how we can overcome this SOQL Query limitation in our integration process?

Comment: is it possible that Mulesoft is not honoring queryMore? or there is some config  limit in Mulesoft.  It doesn't sound like you are using external objects

Comment: +1 cropredy. Also, you can work with inserting 1000 records if this strange problem persists.

Comment: External objects are data stored outside of Salesforce so it would seem strange to query on that through sfdc via mule instead of querying the actual source.  If you are querying sfdc objects that should not be the issue. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=external_object_define.htm

Comment: Yes, I see now that we are not using External objects.  I will look into Mulesoft config suggestion.